# Unable to get oAuth access token for sandbox after making HTTP POST from postman. Access token is returned for Production environment

Tags: oauth2, authorization

I have created a connected app in sandbox. I Have set Selected OAuth Scope = Full
I Have relaxed IP restrictions in connected app policies. When i make HTTP POST to get access token, error is returned with Status code 400. We dont have any security tokens in our sandbox org. hence password is not appended with securtiy token. when i make same HTTP POST for production  URL with details of a connected app from PROD it returns access token successfully

endpoint : https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Header : Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: grant_type = password
client_id = xxxxxxx
client_secret = xxxxxxx
username = 
password =

Status code:400 Bad request is returned
Error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "authentication failure"
}

Comment: Does the user profile have access to the connected app?

Comment: yes user profile has access to connected app.

Comment: Maybe check the login history of the user to see if there's a more specific error. Also, replace test.salesforce.com with your sandbox domain

Comment: Changing from test.salesforce.com to my sandbox domain worked. But in PROD i am using login.salesforce.com and it still works for PROD. so dont know the reason why in sandbox behaviour is different. But it worked Thanks

Comment: You can maybe log a case with Salesforce and ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from test.salesforce.com to my sandbox domain worked